# How to avoid interference between amsmath/fleqn and refstepcounter/label?

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath

When I `pdflatex` the following twice:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{foo}\ref{foo}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{bar}\ref{bar}

\begin{equation} x\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{baz}\ref{baz} \end{equation}

\ref{baz}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{qux}\ref{qux}

\end{document}
```

then I get the following output:

```
1
2
  x1
1
4
```

If I remove `\usepackage{amsmath}` or `[fleqn]` or both then I get

```
1
2
  x3
3
4
```

The latter is what I want.

Can anyone tell me how to get the latter when using amsmath/fleqn ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) allows the end user to insert their own *tags* for numbered equations and therefore collects the body of math environments before processing them. This allows for proper parsing of the content, possibly delaying the execution of `\label` only after the `equation` counter has been stepped. It does, however, retain access to the original LaTeX `\label` via `\ltx@label`, which is appropriate for your use:

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ltxlabel}{\ltx@label}% User-level access to original LaTeX \label
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{foo}\ref{foo}% 1

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{bar}\ref{bar}% 2

\begin{equation} x\refstepcounter{mycounter}\ltxlabel{baz}\ref{baz} \end{equation}

\ref{baz}% 3

\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{qux}\ref{qux}% 4

\end{document}
```

`\ltxlabel` (or `\ltx@label`) will be executed immediately, using whatever counter was previously stepped (via `\refstepcounter`) as a label reference. In contrast, `\label` will only be used to reference the `equation` counter under `amsmath`.