# how to add a user-defined counter in displayed math mode

Tags: amsmath, counters

I want to use a user-defined counter in displayed math mode, and to cross-reference them. When I don't add `amsmath` package, things went well:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{mycnta}
\newcommand{\mycnta}[1]{\refstepcounter{mycnta}\themycnta\label{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \mycnta{e}, \mycnta{f}
    \]
    ref: \ref{e}, \ref{f}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However when I add `amsmath` package, an error occured:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{mycnta}
\newcommand{\mycnta}[1]{\refstepcounter{mycnta}\themycnta\label{#1}}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \mycnta{e}, \mycnta{f}
    \]
    ref: \ref{e}, \ref{f}
\end{document}
```

```
! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'e' will be lost.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7         \mycnta{e}, \mycnta{f}

?
```

I guess that the `\label` command in `\mycnta` conflicts with `amsmath`'s label.

How can I use this user-defined counter with `amsmath`? Or if this demand can't be reached, why can't?

I don't want the **`\tag`** command or something like it, just a counter's cross-reference in math mode.

Comment: Does this help with your question? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620314 You can access the original LaTeX `\label` via `\ltx@label`.

Comment: @marquinho thanks a lot, that's what I need.