# Fix tag placement in align environment when locally switching from reqno to leqno

Tags: align, amsmath, tag

I have been using the solution in [Tag placing with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212085/tag-placing-with-amsmath/212099#212099) to turn on the `leqno` option locally for part of a document.  However, when using the `align` environment from `amsmath`, this leads to spacing problems: the aligned equations are still shifted left to make room for a tag on the right, with the result that they overlap the tag placed on the left.  How can I tell `amsmath` to process the `align` environment in the same way as if I had specified the `leqno` option in the `documentclass`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\leqnos}{\tagsleft@true\let\veqno\@@leqno}
\newcommand{\reqnos}{\tagsleft@false\let\veqno\@@eqno}\makeatother

\begin{document}
\reqnos
\begin{align}
    1+2+3+4+5+6+7&=7+6+5+4+4+3+2+1
    \tag{Boring Equation}       
\end{align}
\leqnos
\begin{align}
    1+2+3+4+5+6+7&=7+6+5+4+4+3+2+1
    \tag{Boring Equation}       
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture showing bad align]

Comment: see `fleqn` environment eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633816/1090

Comment: Interesting.  I tried loading `nnmath` and putting it in a `fleqn` environment but it still overlapped, actually the overlap was even worse!

Comment: I found a sort-of-solution to my problem by consulting the `amsmath` sources: there are four separate definitions of the macro `calc@shift@align` (plus helper macros) depending on which combination of the `fleqn` and `leqno` options is in force, and I was able to pull out a 95-line chunk corresponding to the desired combination.  However I would welcome a more efficient solution if possible, as the editors of the volume I'm contributing to might not be so happy if my contribution has to contain such a big block of latex code.

Comment: yes exactly, that is the issue: that fleqn and leqno are load-time options (to save memory in the 1980s....) so the real code for fleqn or leqno is not there if the options are not used. You can fake simple cases but a real fix requires loading the parts of amsmath not loaded. I thought ncmath did that but I must admit I have never really used it